# Firefox div pixelated background image not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image

I have a little problem. Image-rendering is not working on background image of div in Firefox but in Chrome it works fine.

How can I pixelate the background in Firefox too?

```html
<div id="loadingScreen" class="loadingScreen">
    ...
</div>
```

```css
.loadingScreen{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:50;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#322007;
    background-image:url("../assets/textures/gui/menu_background.png");
    background-size:64px;
    image-rendering:pixelated;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Background image -> [image: Background image]

Result with same code:
[image: Background image in Chrome and Firefox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it.

I've added a line with `crisp-edges` and it looks same.
In Chrome only works with `pixelated` and in Firefox only with `crisp-edges`.

```css
image-rendering: pixelated;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't - this CSS is not supported in Firefox - https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_image-rendering_pixelated

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to pixelate the background?